# Enum extension method can not be called

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

I want to elegantly create an extension method for my `Enum` to print the value as a string. I have written the following static extension method:

```
public enum Genre
{
    Action,
    Thriller,
    Comedy,
    Drama,
    Horror,
    SciFi,
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static string StringBuilder(this Genre g)
    {
        switch (g)
        {
            case Genre.Action: return $"Action";
            case Genre.Thriller: return $"Thriller";
            case Genre.Comedy: return $"Comedy";
            case Genre.Drama: return $"Drama";
            case Genre.Horror: return $"Horror";
            case Genre.SciFi: return $"SciFi";
            default: return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The extension method is called in another class:

```
public class MovieItem
{
    public string? Title { get; }
    public int? RunningTimeMinutes { get; }
    public Enum Genre { get; }

    public MovieItem(string title, int runningTimeMinutes, Genre genre)
    {
        Title = title;
        RunningTimeMinutes = runningTimeMinutes;
        Genre = genre;
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Titel = {Title}, Varighed = {RunningTimeMinutes}, Genre = {Genre.StringBuilder(Genre)}";
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when calling the `Genre.StringBuilder(Genre)` producing error `CS1501 "No overload for method 'StringBuilder' takes 1 arguments"` - but the extension method clearly takes an argument. Have I missed something?

Comment: The `Genre.StringBuilder(Genre)` makes no sense - could you please clarify what you think that line should be doing? Please also re-read the [mre] guidance  on posting code as whole `MovieItem` part should not be there and really enum with one element  (i.e. just `Action`) would be enough to demonstrate the problem. (So far looks like a typo to me as extension is invoked in very strange way and property is essentially untyped)

Comment: I think you forgot how extensions work. When you have `Genre.StringBuilder(x)` the first argument to `StringBuilder()` is `Genre` and the second argument is `x`. The compiler treats an extension method as if the first parameter is implicit, but you can also call it `Extensions.StringBuilder(Genre, Genre)` which makes it obvious why it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to change `public Enum Genre { get; }` to `public Genre Genre { get; }`
And call your extension as `Genre.StringBuilder()`

Comment: @Aleksandar and don't name your objects with identifiers that are common to .net Framework. In this case `StringBuilder`. StringBuilder is a well-known commonly used type

Comment: This solved my issue - thanks! Why can't I call the the extension with my argument though? Does it implicitly known, as I have used `this` under the definition the method must be applied to the enum called?

Comment: You could do it this way `Extensions.StringBuilder(Genre)`. But the feature of extensions is that you can "extend" existed type functionality. You could read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 0):

By the way, formatting an enum member by its name can be drastically reduced to this very line:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string StringBuilder(this Genre g) => Enum.IsDefined(g) ? $"{g:G}" : "";
}
```

or even fully generic for any Enum definition:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetMemberName<TEnum>(this TEnum e)
      where TEnum : Enum => Enum.IsDefined(e) ? $"{e:G}" : "";
}
```